# Getting VIN's of North American Vehicles

Tags: scan-tool, vin

I'm considering getting a [BlueDriver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00652G4TS) scan tool, but to use it's reports feature either it needs to detect or you need to manually enter a North American VIN.  Since I live outside the USA, I was wondering if there is a reliable way to get North American VIN codes so I could manually enter them?

Comment: Do you mean where to locate the VIN on the car or do you just need a database of some kind?

Comment: @Zshoulders a database of some kind so I could look up equivalent VIN numbers for a non-us vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

A VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) code is unique to each vehicle - it gives all the information such as which manufacturing plant right down to which radio and speakers were fitted etc.
If the scan tool you are looking at is limited to North American vehicles (which surprises me - most i checked were targeted at the manufacturers VW, Landrover, GM etc) then I suggest you look at other ones. I bought one in the UK for a vehicle used in Switzerland - vehicle made in UK - it works fine.